# How can I order by date in jpa query

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

Please I want to write a jpa query for this table: payment_transaction

I am making a http request with a list of taxpayer references (since it is unique). I want to get all last payment_transaction record for all taxpayers with taxpayer_reference in my http request list of taxpayer_reference using a single query. 
 I know that: 
`paymentTransactionRepository.findAllByTaxPayerReferenceIn(List<String> taxPayerReferences)`
 will give me all the payment transaction records that has a taxPayerReference in the parameter I will pass but I want to get the last payment made by each taxPayerReference. I guess I should order by paymentDate in descending order and get the first record for each taxPayerReference as well
**PS: In single jpa query**
I don't know if that's possible. Please help me write the query. 
Thanks
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please edit your question with all the code you have done already so we can help you, if you dont know how to properly make questions in here, have a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Padua I have edited my question. Please can you look at it now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like below.

```
findByAgeOrderByLastnameDesc(Long age)
```

Which will be generated as below when you run

```
where x.age = ?1 order by x.lastname desc
```

For your particular example,

```
paymentTransactionRepository.findAllByTaxPayerReferenceInOrderByPaymentDateDesc(List<String> taxPayerReferences)
```

More examples on this available [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)